# Wie nennt man das, wenn ein Reißverschluss nicht mehr zusammenhält?

Tags: single-word-request

Manchmal öffnet sich ein Reißverschluss unterhalb des Schiebers, wo die Zähne eigentlich ineinander verhakt sein sollten:

[image: kaputter Reißverschluss]

Gibt es für dieses Nicht-mehr-Zusammenhalten der Zähne einen Begriff? Wie sagt oder beschreibt man das im Alltag, mit möglichst wenigen Worten, so dass ein Zuhörer, der kein Bild vor Augen hat, versteht, was gemeint ist?

Comment: schei.. is kaputt

Comment: _Der Reißverschluss ist (unten) aufgegangen / hält nicht mehr._

Answer (score 4):

Bei uns im Nordosten Deutschlands sagt man einfach

> Der Reißverschluss ist *kaputt*.

oder etwas formeller

> Der Reißverschluss ist *defekt*.

Wie man es in anderen Regionen im Alltag sagt, kann ich nicht sagen.

Zwar sind *kaputt* und *defekt* Oberbegriffe, die alle möglichen Defekte bezeichnen, doch bei diesem Satz stelle ich mir genau den Sachverhalt vor, der auf dem Bild zu sehen ist, allein schon weil das der häufigste Defekt bei Reißverschlüssen sein dürfte. Wenn es nur ums Klemmen ginge, würde ich sagen

> Der Reißverschluss *klemmt*.

Seltener habe ich auch schon gehört, der Reißverschluss sei *aufgeplatzt*, wobei es dann eher die pralle Jacke ist, die *am* Reißverschluss *aufgeplatzt* ist, als der Reißverschluss *an sich*.

Comment: *Defekt* oder *kaputt* kann aber bedeuten, dass sich der Reissverschluss lediglich nicht mehr verschieben lässt (klemmt).

Answer (score 3):

Obwohl die deutsche Sprache für zumindest gefühlt fast jeden Sonderfall einen Begriff hat, müsste die Antwort hier lauten:

> Es gibt keinen speziellen Begriff für einen Reißverschluss mit diesem Schaden.

Natürlich kann man das Schadensbild beschreiben, und mit Deiner Frage bist Du schon gut unterwegs. Ich würde sagen „der Reißverschluss hält nicht mehr zusammen“ oder „der Reißverschluss ist hinter dem Schieber aufgegangen“ (oder „unter“ bei senkrechten Modellen).

Answer (score 3):

**aufgespleißt**

**aufgespreizt**

Kaputt war auch meine erste Idee. :) Man könnte von einer Entgleisung sprechen - da denkt man aber vielleicht eher, dass mindestens eine Seite ganz rausgesprungen ist - oder out-of-sync, das ist aber wieder nicht richtig deutsch - asynchron, entsynchronisiert. Oder in X-Form geraten (statt Y).

Seile und Schnüre, deren Enden auseinandergehen, spleißen auf, sind aufgespleißt, das würde hier passen, bzw. auch aufgespreizt, wobei der Reisverschluss beim öffnen ja bestimmungsgemäß zu einer Seite hin aufspreizt, von daher müsste man sagen **beidseitig aufgespreizt/aufgespleißt**.

Sonst spreizen sich vor allem Beine, auch bei Geräten (Tripod) oder die Schenkel eines Zirkels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Wie sagt oder beschreibt man das im Alltag, mit möglichst wenigen Worten, so dass ein Zuhörer, der kein Bild vor Augen hat, versteht, was gemeint ist?

Der Reißverschluss hält nicht mehr zusammen.

Comment: Auch schön kurz und beschreibt noch besser als *kaputt* den Zustand.

Answer (score -3):

Ich stelle

> Reißverschluss-Inkontinenz

zur Diskussion. Nach [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Inkontinenz) bezeichnet *Inkontinenz* im nichtmedizinischen Gebrauch die

> Unfähigkeit, etwas zurückhalten zu können

Comment: Ich finde die Antwort gut (und der downvote stammt nicht von mir), weil ich hier langsam den Eindruck habe, dass es sich um Beschäftigungstherapie handelt. Wie nennt man das eigentlich, wenn das Auto wegen eines Wassertropfens im Vergaser nicht mehr anspringt? Da gibt es doch bestimmt auch ein paar furchtbar ernsthafte Antwortmöglichkeiten. Oder man sagt einfach kaputt, futschikato, springt nicht an ...

Comment: Also ich finde den Vorschlag kreativ (daher +1). Ich befürchte nur, dass die Assoziation mit der medizinischen Bedeutung zu stark ist, als dass sich der Begriff im Alltag durchsetzen könnte.

Comment: Ich bezweifle, ob es dem Fragesteller hilft hier einen Begriff zu erfinden, den niemand kennt oder verwendet. Bei dem Vorgeschlagenen würde man sich auch eher fragen, warum ein Reißverschluss undicht sein oder tropfen sollte. Was die Definition angeht: was soll der nicht mehr zurückhalten können? Ergibt für mich alles keinen Sinn. Es gibt zwar Ausdrücke, wie Sprachinkontinenz, aber bei denen passt das noch halbwegs.